# Configuration of tomcat 7 as servlet container only

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I am going to use Tomcat as servlet container only.
No static, jsp or jsf. Java servlets only.

Do I need listeners in configuration? Can I remove them?

How to improve configuration for my task? 
Links or advise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of improvements? Memory improvements? Do u want to disallow access of jsp and jsf and only want to allow servlet?

Comment: Memory improvements? -- yes. Performance improvements -- yes. And, yes  I want to remove support of jsp and jsf and only allow servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the listeners thats appear in the server.xml, I recommend you to read the next link about the listeners and you can decide what remove or not.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html

If i were you and you know that you are not going to use jsp pages i will remove the Jasper Listener user to compile de JSP files.

Comment: yes, listeners in server.xml in <server> component.